# Flask: How to pass all GET parameters to redirect?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to do something like this:

```
return redirect(app.config['FB_APP_URL'], request.args)
```

But I get an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this or do I have to loop through request.args ?
thanks

**update:**

Going with Paolo 's solution, this is the solution that worked for me.

```
params = urlparse(request.url).query
        return redirect(app.config['FB_APP_URL']+"?"+params)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong cause the second parameter to `redirect` is the httpcode (301, 302, ecc).

You can use `url_for` to create the full url, something like:

```
full_url = url_for('.index', **request.args)
return redirect(full_url)
```

Comment: Not sure, if I understood it correctly.  I would like to take all current get parameters and pass it to a different URL -> app.config['FB_APP_URL']

Comment: ahh now I understand. Let me try it please

Comment: if it's an url outside of your flask app (external site) then you may use `urlparse' module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html the key of your question is that all your GET args are in request.args that acts like a dict